# Android phone-to-phone notification over the internet

Tags: android, android-networking

I would like to develop a small application which can send notifications or communicate from one phone to another over the internet.

Could any please suggest me how can I start with this project?

Comment: Have a Look Its Helpfull for u http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139

Comment: as far as i know most cellphone-networks block inbound networkconnections so a server on your cellphone will only be reachable via wlan but not via gsm/umts/...

Answer (score 0):

Look for Google Cloud Messaging: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

There's considerable setup. You need to activate GCM for your app in the developer panel, get yourself an API key, and depending on use case, maybe you'll need an XMPP server as well.

Comment: hi its that possible we use GCM without my webserver. Because what I want to communicate phone-to-phone is without any server.

Comment: If you don't want a server, just communicate over IP. You'll have to find some way to know what the IPs are if you don't use a server.